# Getting SEGV / core dumped when running Perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, segmentation-fault, coredump

When I try to run the Perl debugger I'm getting a SEGV error:

```
Signal SEGV at /opt/csw/lib/perl/csw/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm line 240.
        Term::ReadLine::Gnu::new("Term::ReadLine", "perldb", GLOB(0x81c1168), GLOB(0x81873a0)) called at /opt/csw/share/perl/5.10.1/perl5db.pl line 6073
        DB::setterm called at /opt/csw/share/perl/5.10.1/perl5db.pl line 2237
        DB::DB called at -e line 1
 Abort (core dumped)
```

The errors takes place with any Perl code and I think is due to the debugger using Term::ReadLine::Gnu::new.

Using gdb to get the stack trace, I get the following:

```
Core was generated by `/opt/csw/bin/perl -de$a++'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0xfeaabbc5 in kill () from /lib/libc.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0xfeaabbc5 in kill () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xfef0c748 in Perl_apply () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#2  0xfeeff1ee in Perl_pp_chown () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#3  0xfeeb6721 in Perl_runops_standard () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#4  0xfee570da in Perl_call_sv () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#5  0xfeeac2c8 in Perl_sighandler () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#6  0xfeea8173 in Perl_csighandler () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#7  0xfeaa8ecf in __sighndlr () from /lib/libc.so.1
#8  0xfea9eb8f in call_user_handler () from /lib/libc.so.1
#9  <signal handler called>
#10 0xfe82b828 in baudrate () from /lib/libcurses.so.1
#11 0xfe7ede48 in _nc_setupterm () from /opt/csw/lib/libncurses.so.5
#12 0xfe7ee010 in tgetent () from /opt/csw/lib/libncurses.so.5
#13 0xfe88659a in _rl_init_terminal_io () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libreadline.so.6
#14 0xfe86eb32 in readline_initialize_everything () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libreadline.so.6
#15 0xfe86ea22 in rl_initialize () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libreadline.so.6
#16 0xfe8d6e1d in XS_Term__ReadLine__Gnu__XS_rl_initialize () from /opt/csw/lib/perl/csw/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/Gnu.so
#17 0xfeebe7ee in Perl_pp_entersub () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#18 0xfeeb6721 in Perl_runops_standard () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#19 0xfee568f1 in S_run_body () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#20 0xfee56813 in perl_run () from /opt/csw/lib/i386/libperl.so
#21 0x08050b48 in main ()
```

I would greatly appreciate any help/clues.

Thanks!

Comment: Reinstall `Term::ReadLine::Gnu'?

Comment: Are you using an old version of Perl (you appear to be using Perl 5.10)?  If that is the case, maybe you could try a more recent version of Perl.  I believe 5.24 just got released/dropped a few days ago.  Maybe try 5.22 along with what user @mob suggested above.  It would be helpful if we had an idea of your environment and some code (if possible),  HTH

Comment: Yes, perl 5.10 is _very_ old. Perl developers won't take a bug report unless you're using the latest stable release. Depending on your distro, you may want to build perl from source from https://www.perl.org When I got fedora 22, it came with perl 5.20 and started segfaulting on scripts that had run for a decade. See my answer here for what I did to install perl: https://serverfault.com/questions/741186/cpan-is-using-old-perl-version-to-install-modules/741216#741216